# Accessing localhost externally?

Tags: django, localhost, static-ip-address

This is probably a very basic question. I SSH to my virtual Ubuntu server and start a django webserver running on localhost:

```
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB): 6.6MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

April 13, 2016 - 14:16:19
Django version 1.9.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

The Ubuntu server has a static IP [x.xxx.xxx.xxx] so from another machine on another network I try to access the above website in a browser using that static IP address:

```
x.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000
```

But I get:

```
This site can’t be reached

x.xxx.xxx.xxx refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

So I assume that I cannot access the website like this and that is only available on the host it self even though the host has an external/static IP address?

**Edit:**

The answer is also in:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your web server on `0.0.0.0:8000`, then externally you would use either ip or host name to access. Using `0.0.0.0` means the django service would listen to all configured network interfaces.

Check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) on details about 0.0.0.0.

Another [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1) on serverfault could be helpful.

Comment: don't you mean 0.0.0.0:8000? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server

Comment: Yea sorry for the typo.